# What does the "Low morale" effect on items do in Dragon Age: Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I've come across one or two items with "Low morale" listed as an effect (mainly with the gift-become-items from the Prank DLC), but what does that do to the wearer?

I myself would guess that it impacts on Mental Resistance (being low morale = run away more often) and maybe have an effect on hit rate, but does anyone know / can confirm what effect it has on the wearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low morale means that it reduces the approval rating you have with that companion. It likely reduces the combat bonuses that party member has when it is equipped. For example, the Butterfly sword on a low approval Sten may reduce the strength bonus he gains with high approval.

Answer (score 0):

Low morale for sten drops his defence by 5 points when equipped. As for lilianas Ugly Boots they might do the same. So TBH 5 points is not that much so equipping a whole set will take the negative stat away.

Answer (score -5):

Nothing. It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: This contradicts what the previous answer has stated.  Do you have any proof whatsoever that it doesn't do anything?